# PHP PDO class : Data dosn't appear in my index.php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Every thing is ok with my script but the data doesn't appear in my index.php :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GWdj.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxEdE.png

### index.php :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DB Connextion Test</title>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Prenom</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        require ('Database.php');
        $db = new Database();
        $dataSet = $db->getUsers('SELECT * FROM `users`');
        if (!empty($dataSet)) {
            foreach ($dataSet as $data) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->getUserId().'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->getUserNom().'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->getUserPrenom().'</td>';
                echo '</tr>'; 
            }
        } else
            echo 'No Result Found!';
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

### Database.php :

```
<?php
require ('Users.php');

class Database {

    public $db_name = 'authsys_db';
    public $host = 'localhost';
    public $user = 'root';
    public $password = '';
    public $con = '';
    public $db_handle = '';

    public $testMode = TRUE;

    public function __construct () {
        $this->con = sprintf('mysql:dbname=%s;host=%s', $this->db_name, $this->host);
        if ($this->testMode) {
            $this->db_handle = new PDO($this->con, $this->user, $this->password,
                                       array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
        } else {
            $this->db_handle = new PDO($this->con, $this->user, $this->password);
        }
    }

    public function  getUsers ($sql) {
        $stmt = $this->db_handle->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $dataSet[] = new Users($row);
        }
        if (!empty($dataSet))
            return $dataSet;
        else 
            return NULL;
    }

}
?>
```

### Users.php :

```
<?php

class Users {

    private $id;
    private $nom;
    private $prenom;

    public function __construnct ($row) {

        $this->id = $row['ID'];
        $this->nom = $row['nom'];
        $this->prenom = $row['prenom'];
    }

    public function getUserId () {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUserNom () {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function getUserPrenom () {
        return $this->prenom;
    }
}

?>
```

in my database there is only one row in users table, i get the row but empty, I really don't know what to do here... little Help !!

Comment: OOOH, what a stupid mistake.... Thank you @Debflav :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, change `__construnct`  to `__construct` :

```
public function __construnct ($row) {
     $this->id = $row['ID'];
     $this->nom = $row['nom'];
     $this->prenom = $row['prenom'];
```

}

Indeed, you got one User but all his properties are empty due to this typo. In addition, maybe its not the best way to create the User by setting all his properties in the `__construct()`.

Comment: @Devflav I used the properties in another function like this :
`public function getUser ($row) {
     $this->id = $row['ID'];
     $this->nom = $row['nom'];
     $this->prenom = $row['prenom'];
}`

but it didn't work :/

How can i do it ??!

Comment: I don't get it. Where are you doing this and why it doesn't work ?

Comment: It's Done. Thank you by the way :D